# Dropping groups and sub-groups from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have two item lists:

```
item_list = [
    'item 01-01-01', 'item 01-01-02', 'item 01-01-03',
    'item 01-02-01', 'item 01-02-02', 'item 01-02-03',
    'item 01-03-01', 'item 01-03-02', 'item 01-03-03', 

    'item 02-01-01', 'item 02-01-02', 'item 02-01-03',
    'item 02-02-01', 'item 02-02-02', 'item 02-02-03',
    'item 02-03-01', 'item 02-03-02', 'item 02-03-03',

    'item 03-01-01', 'item 03-01-02', 'item 03-01-03',
    'item 03-02-01', 'item 03-02-02', 'item 03-02-03',
    'item 03-03-01', 'item 03-03-02', 'item 03-03-03']


faulty_item_list = [
    'item 01-01-01', 
    'item 01-02-01', 'item 01-02-02', 'item 01-02-03',
    'item 01-03-01', 'item 01-03-02', 'item 01-03-03', 

    'item 02-01-01', 'item 02-01-02', 'item 02-01-03',
    'item 02-02-01', 'item 02-02-02', 'item 02-02-03',
    'item 02-03-01', 'item 02-03-02', 'item 02-03-03',

    'item 03-01-01', 'item 03-01-02', 'item 03-01-03',
                     'item 03-02-02', 'item 03-02-03',
    'item 03-03-01', 'item 03-03-02', 'item 03-03-03']
```

[image: Item lists]

And I want to drop all items that make up a group or sub-group so that I can return the following items:

```
['item 01-01-01', 'item 03-02-02', 'item 03-02-03']
```

What maybe the best the approach?

Comment: How are you defining a group/sub-group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this with list comprehension:

```
[ item
  for item in faulty_item_list

  # counts how many elements have the same start as the item, except for the last 2 chars
  if sum( other_item.startswith(item[:-2]) 
          for other_item in faulty_item_list ) < 3 
]
```

Another way to do it, might be better for larger lists:

```
group_dict = {}

for item in faulty_item_list:
    group_id = item[:-2]
    if group_id not in group_dict:
        group_dict[group_id] = [ 1, [item] ]
    else:
        group_dict[group_id][0] += 1
        group_dict[group_id][1].append(item)

[ item 
  for group_id,(count,item_list) in group_dict.items() 
  for item in item_list 
  if count < 3 ]
```